# Beginner with Spartan 6, syntax issue

Tags: vhdl, hdl

I'm writing a simple program using Spartan 6 for signed numbers but this error pops up says :hdl 806"near line 12 syntax error"

```
    library IEEE;
use IEEE.STD_LOGIC_1164.ALL;
use IEEE.NUMERIC_STD.ALL;

entity Multiplier_Top is
    Port ( 
    
           A       : in    signed (15 downto 0);
           B       : in   signed (15 downto 0);
           Sum     : out  signed (15 downto 0);
           Overflow   : out  STD_LOGIC;
        );
end Multiplier_Top;

architecture Behavioral of Multiplier_Top is

  signal Sum_Int    signed (16 downto 0)  :=(others=>'0');

begin
    
      Sum_Int    <= Resize(A,17) + B;
      Sum      <= Sum_Int(15 downto 0);
      Overflow    <= Sum_Int(16) xor Sum_Int(15);

end Behavioral;
```

Comment: maybe you should start with a good book or tutorial and some simulations in Modelsim, Xilinx simulator or GHDL, before starting with synthesis. You still need to learn the basics and learn what error messages mean.

Answer (score 1):

There are 2 syntax error in the design:

- Line 11: Remove the `;` after `out  STD_LOGIC;` so it becomes `out std_logic`
- Line 17: Insert a `:` in `Sum_Int signed` so it becomes `Sum_Int : signed`

Some other comments:

- Line 17: Remove default value assign `:=(others=>'0')`, since that is not required when output is assigned by continuous assignment in line 21
- Line 17 and others: Use VHDL attributes line `'length` to avoid constants in code

The code can then look like this:

```
library IEEE;
use IEEE.STD_LOGIC_1164.all;
use IEEE.NUMERIC_STD.all;

entity Multiplier_Top is
  port (    
    A        : in  signed (15 downto 0);
    B        : in  signed (15 downto 0);
    Sum      : out signed (15 downto 0);
    Overflow : out std_logic
    );
end Multiplier_Top;

architecture Behavioral of Multiplier_Top is

  signal Sum_Int : signed (A'length downto 0);  -- Length one bit more than A, assuming same length as B

begin

  Sum_Int  <= Resize(A, Sum_Int'length) + B;
  Sum      <= Sum_Int(Sum'range);
  Overflow <= Sum_Int(Sum_Int'left) xor Sum_Int(Sum_Int'left - 1);

end Behavioral;
```

Comment: _"Use VHDL attributes like `'length` to avoid constants in code"_, well, that depends on what you want to achieve. e.g. If you specifically want bit 15, use `'left` and increase the size of the range, you're screwed.

Comment: To determine overflow in a signed addition, the check can be done using the 2 left most bits of the intermediate sum with a protection bit (Sum_Int).  Writing the code with reference to the leftmost and the 2nd leftmost bits using VHDL attributes appears to show the intention more clearly, than using "magic" numbers like 16 and 15.

Comment: Yeah. In this case.... ;) although the entity is actually called "multiplier" 

Comment: Yeps, that looks misleading ☺️